# Is it possible to distinguish between SpaCy entity types?

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

Is it possible to distinguish between SpaCy entity types? e.g. whether the recognized ORG is a company, agency or institution or whether the recognized FAC is an airport highway, bridge etc.?